# SFDX: Is it possible to push to a sandbox from VS Code?

Tags: salesforcedx, sandbox, vs-code

I have successfully connected VS Code and pushed to several different SF environments, including Trailhead, Developer, and Production. But I can't figure out how to push to a sandbox. It looks like you can't connect to a sandbox the same way you would with another org (using SFDX: Authorize an Org from the command palette), but when I do it directly from the command line
`sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com/`
it seems to work (I get a message in terminal that I've `Successfully authorized <mySandboxUsernam> with org ID <myOrgId>`)

But after authorizing, if I try to right-click on a folder to deploy, I don't get a contextual menu option of `SFDX: Deploy Source to Org` as I would when authorized with other instances. Is there any way to push code to a sandbox? I don't mind doing it from the command line if that's the only way, but I can't find any documentation on how to do it.

Comment: Related: the official feature of interacting with non-source tracked orgs, such as sandboxes, is in beta. [Develop Against Any Org (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the force:source:deploy command (not available in the UI, as far as I can tell).

The basic syntax is as follows:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p source-dir/ -u username-or-alias
```

This should work fine from any terminal you open in VS Code.

Answer (score 5):

sfdcfox layout out a good option. At time of writing, though, [force:source:deploy is still in beta](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_any_org.htm) (as of Winter '19, API v45.0).

If you aren't comfortable with the beta designation, the other option is to convert from source form to metadata api form

`sfdx force:source:convert -d targetDirectory`

and then deploy using the metadata api

`sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d targetDirectory -u usernameOrAlias`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how much of this is due to changes in the CLI and Extensions since Feb 2019, but what is now (May 2019) the case is:

- The `SFDX: Authorize an Org` command in VS Code prompts for the login URL, allowing you to specify test.salesforce.org for a Sandbox.
- The context menu item `SFDX: Deploy Source to Org` works for the `defaultusername` for the project. The `SFDX: Authorize an Org` command sets the authorized org to be the default for the project. But if you use `sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername` you'll achieve the same result.
- Towards the left side of the VS Code status bar, the default username for the current project is indicated (with a plug icon). You can click it and select a different, already-auth'd org to be the project default, auth to a new org and set it as the default, or spin up a new scratch org and have it become the default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can now source track changes between your project and dev sandboxes using source tracking for sandboxes beta feature - [Track Changes Between the Project and the Sandbox (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_sandboxes_source_tracking.htm)

Which means you can start using source:pull & source:push with sandboxes !